# Is it possible to apply rules to a Objective C class properties for RPG attributes?

Tags: objective-c, class, properties, validationrules

In Objective C you write 20 or so RPG attributes  like:

```
@interface Employee : NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
    NSString *nickname;
    NSString *filename;

    // Attributes
    int personality;
    int behaviour;
    int attitude;
    int workrate;
    int morale;
    int health;
}
```

I want to make all my RPG attributes listen to rules. ie: Personality can be 1-99, health can be 1-100, morale can be 0-100 and so on.

I'd like to know if I can make a class for Attributes that will automatically test whether the number stored is within rules; this way I can save time having to test it for like 20 different fields.

I guess I could use a dictionary, but even if I do this I'd like to make sure the attributes listen to rules.

Is this kind of thing possible?

Comment: I suspect you're pretty quickly going to end up with a relatively complex model layer.  You might want to investigate Core Data as it is exactly designed to maintain object graphs, with validation.

Comment: Yeah it would get quite complex. I'll look into Core Data to sort it all out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you'd generally make each attribute a `@property` and provide a custom setter which either rejects or corrects invalid values:

.h file:

```
@interface Employee : NSObject

@property (assign, nonatomic, readwrite) int personality;
// others omitted

@end
```

.m file:

```
@implementation Employee

- (void)setPersonality:(int)personality {
    if (personality < 1)
        personality = 1;
    else if (personality > 99)
        personality = 99;
    // _personality is an auto-generated backing instance variable
    _personality = personality;
}

// - (int)personality { ... } will be auto-generated
```

If every one of those attributes has a min/max value then create an `static` function to restrict the value:

```
static int restrict(int minValue, int maxValue, int value) {
    if (value < minValue)
        value = minValue;
    else if (value > maxValue)
        value = maxValue;
    return value;
}
```

...

```
- (void)setPersonality:(int)personality {
    // _personality is an auto-generated backing instance variable
    _personality = restrict(1, 99, personality);
}
```

Note: that you must not assign `_personality` (and friends) directly; you must use `self.personality = 34;` or `employee.personality = 34;` to invoke the setter.